# get iFrame location.href from it self

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, postmessage

I have an iFrame and I want to get the location.href of this, not from parent, but from it self. 
Here the code where i want to get this:

```
var scanForUrl = "<script>window.setInterval(function(){ parent.postMessage( //Location Href of iFrame// , '*'); }, 2000);</script>";
```

I don't know if it's possible, I entrust to you.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

iframe uses the src attribute not href

```
let source = $("iframe").attr("src");
```

Comment: I need to access location.href inside the iFrame not from parent.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean could you post the iframe contents?